# 1013 error. This attibute may only be used on class property definitions. I have 7 of this error in my code

Tags: actionscript-3

all of these functions are getting this error. The setuplayer, the makeBalloons and the makeBalloon. I copied and pasted this code from my teacher. So I don't know what it could been stuck on trying to get these ballons to spawn in a game. Before I added the touch layer it would run but no balloons spawned. So I decided to add a touch layer and then I got these errors.

```
        private function setupTouchLayer(evt: Event): void {
            touchLayer.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 0);
            touchLayer.graphics.drawRect(0, 0,stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
            touchLayer.graphics.endFill();


        }

        private function makeBalloons(): void {
            balloonSpawnCounter++;

            if (balloonSpawnCounter > balloonSpawnDelay) {
                balloonSpawnCounter = 0;
                balloonSpawnDelay -= difficultyRate;
                difficulty += difficultyRate;
                makeBalloon();
            }
        }

        private function makeBalloon(): void {
            var i: int;
            for (i = 0; i < Math.floor(difficulty); i++) {
                var newBalloon: Balloon = new MouseBalloon();

                newBalloon.x = 1050;
                newBalloon.y = Math.random() * 300 + 150;

                newBalloon.xVel = (-Math.random() * difficulty) - 5;
                newBalloon.sinMeter = Math.random() * 10;
                newBalloon.bobValue = Math.random() * difficulty;

                newBalloon.addEventListener(Particle.PURGE_EVENT, purgeBalloonHandler);

                balloonsLayer.addChild(newBalloon);
                balloons.push(newBalloon);
            }
        }

        private function purgeBalloonHandler(evt: Event): void {
            var targetBalloon: Particle = Particle(evt.target);
            purgeBalloon(targetBalloon);
        }

        private function purgeBalloon(targetBalloon: Particle): void {
            targetBalloon.removeEventListener(Particle.PURGE_EVENT, purgeBalloonHandler);
            try {
                var i: int;
                for (i = 0; i < balloons.length; i++) {
                    if (balloons[i].name == targetBalloon.name) {
                        balloons.splice(i, 1);
                        balloonsLayer.removeChild(targetBalloon);
                        i = balloons.length;
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Error)

            {
                trace("Failed to delete arrow!", e);
            }
        }

        private function hitTest(shark: Particle): void {
            for each(var balloon: Balloon in balloons) {
                if (balloon.status != "Dead" && balloon.hitTestPoint(shark.x, shark.y)) {
                    balloon.destroy();

                }
            }
        }

        private function update(evt: Event): void {


            for each(var balloon: Particle in balloons) {
                balloon.update();
            }


            makeBalloons();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Do you actually have a class or you're trying to paste that on the frames?

Comment: @c.todd - Did the answer help solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you are copying and pasting code from a class file, into a timeline, you have to remove any `package` or  `class` blocks,  and any scope keywords like `private`,`public`,`protected`, `final` etc.

For example,  if you had the following .as file:

```
package com.mystuff {
   public class ExampleClass extends Object {
       public function ExampleClass(){
           trace("Hello World!");
       }

       private function doSomething():void {
           trace("Doing something...");
       }
   }
}
```

To put that on a timeline keyframe, you'd have to change it to:

```
trace("Hello World");

function doSomething():void {
    trace("Doing Something...");
}
```

The function that has the same name as the class name, you want to be by itself at the top of the code.  All other functions, just remove the public and private keywords.

---

Now, if you'd like to use that code in an actual class file (which is good), you would do the following: (assuming you just have the code and not a file, and are using Animate/FlashPro as your IDE).

In AnimateCC, go to file -> new and choose ActionScript 3.0 Class. Give it the class name that matches what you see in the code.

Paste your code.

Save the file in the same directory as your .fla, assuming the code starts with `package {`.   If the code starts with something like `package com.mystuff`, the file should saved in a subfolder called `mystuff` that is inside another folder called `com` which is in the same directory as your .fla.

To use that class file in the timeline (or another class file), you'd have to instantiate it like so:

```
import com.mystuff.ExampleClass;

var ec:ExampleClass = new ExampleClass();

ec.dosomething();
```

---

If you are using a class file, but are getting that error, it probably means you've accidentally closed your class block,  like the following:

```
package {
    public class ExampleClass {

    }//if you put an extra one of these closing curly braces in your code, it will end your class, or if you on purpose do it like this example.

    private function dosomething():void {
        //will error because this function needs to live inside the class block
    }
}
```